# Add additional address type to existing table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema, database-performance, sqlperformance

Suppose I have this table in live prod for many years:

```
[UserContactInfo]
[UserContactInfoId] uniqueidentifier not null
[UserId] uniqueidentifier not null PK to [User] table
[FirstName] varchar(50) null
[LastName] varchar(50) null
[Street] varchar(200) null
[City] varchar(50) null
[State] varchar(2) null
[Zip] varchar(10) null
many other fields
```

Currently total max row byte count is currently only 1K -- far less than 8K per-row limit.

Currently there are around 10 million rows or about 9GB.

Let's say that data-migration is very painful due to the large table size , the necessity of running all operations in transactions , and the business negatives of extensive database maintenance window.

Now I want to add the mailing address.

Options 1 : I could either add additional columns:

```
[MailingStreet] varchar(200) null
[MailingCity] varchar(50) null
[MailingState] varchar(2) null
[MailingZip] varchar(10) null
```

Option 2 : I could type the address:

```
[AddressType] byte not null
```

corresponding to a C# enum enforced on write

```
enum AddressType {
Physical=1,
Mailing=2}
```

and during db maintenance job run a script to update all existing rows to [AddressType]=1

My question is which option will be better performing?

Option 1 negatives:

(a) initially all rows will have 4 unused columns and likely even after many years it will be low % of rows with actual data. But I believe SQL Server only requires a single bit to record that a col is null.
(b) it moves the row slightly closer to the 8K boundary ( albeit still a long ways off ) 
(c) if we need another address type it means more cols

Option 2 negatives:

(a) potentially sometime in the future the table could have twice as many rows. I could add a compound index on `[UserId],[AddressType]` and I'm sure  SQL Server has various tricks to optimize performance, but could I doubt it would ever approach the performance of a table half the size?

Does anyone have better insight into the trade-offs of Option 1 vs Option 2?

Comment: Your 1a and 2a points contradict each other. 1a says that you're unlikely to have many mailing addresses. 2a says that practically everyone will have both addresses. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 would be the more standard approach. It means that you're not duplicating column definitions (consider what happens if you decide city needs to expand to 60 chars), and is more amenable to later additions (more address types).

It also gives you more flexibility in querying. If you have any queries that treat all addresses as "equal" for the purposes of the query (it doesn't matter what the address is being used for) then it's straightforward to write, and if you need to restrict to particular address types you can apply a simple filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Contrast that with Option 1 - if you want to query all addresses equally then you need to name all address columns individually in the `WHERE` clause and need to apply care to avoid mixing individual elements (e.g. if you're trying to find all uses of `Tampa, CO`, you need to make sure that you don't mix the city from the mailing address with the state of the physical address). And if you want to allow people to filter to individual address types, you have to translate e.g. UI selections into separate column names, usually leading to dynamic SQL becoming required.

---

(Depending on the Use Cases, you may have a separate decision to make regarding first and last names and whether they're tied to the address or the user, to decide whether they belong in this table still, now that it's modelling multiple addresses)